# How to debug multiple threads/runnables at the same time in netbeans

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I have 3 classes:

A main class that creates the thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Class1)
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Class2)

t.start()
t1.start()
```

Class1 implements Runnable

Class2 implements Runnable

In netbeans, how do i debug through Class1 and Class2 at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place the breakpoint inside each of the `run()` methods within `Class1` and `Class2`. In the `Debugging` tab you can see all the `Threads`. 
[image]

When you are stepping through a thread and a breakpoint is hit in another thread, the IDE gives you the option to switch to the other thread or continue stepping through the current thread. 
[image]
If you look in the Debugging window you can see that the current thread (Thread_Jirka) is indicated by a green bar in the margin. The thread that invoked the notification by hitting the breakpoint (Thread_Roman) is indicated by a yellow bar and the thread icon indicates that the thread is suspended by a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Just debug the code. Put breakpoints where you want the debugger to stop (inside `run()` method of `Class1` and `Class2` possibly). The IDE also has a threads view where you can see state of all threads and you can interrupt them.

BTW: your code does not compile.